# Make new list of dictionaries from existing list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following list of dictionaries:

```
dict1 = [{"id": 1, "name": "tamara", "age":23}, 
         {"id": 1, "name": "mia", "age":14}, 
         {"id": 1, "name": "teo", "age":33}, 
         {"id": 2, "name": "maya", "age":30}}
```

I would like to create new list of dictionaries from the existing list of dictionaries where If I have the same "id":1 three times in dict1 then don't repeat them in the list and rather have dict in a dict:

```
 dict2 = [{"id": 1, newkey: [{"name": "tamara", "age":23}, 
                             {"name":"mia", "age":14}, 
                             {"name": "teo", "age":33}]}, 
          {"id": 2, "name": "maya", "age":30}}
```

This is what I want to achieve any suggestion how?

Comment: `dict1` is not a dictionary, and furthermore not even syntactically correct Python. Please double check your code before submitting your question. Fix it now by editing, please.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
dict1 = [{"id": 1, "name": "tamara", "age":23}, {"id": 1, "name": "mia", "age":14}, {"id": 1, "name": "teo", "age":33}, {"id": 2, "name": "maya", "age":30}]
new_d = [[a, list(b)] for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(dict1, key=lambda x:x['id']), key=lambda x:x['id'])]
dict2 = [{'id':a, 'new_key':[{c:d for c, d in i.items() if c != 'id'} for i in b]} for a, b in new_d]
```

Output:

```
[{'new_key': [{'age': 23, 'name': 'tamara'}, {'age': 14, 'name': 'mia'}, {'age': 33, 'name': 'teo'}], 'id': 1}, {'new_key': [{'age': 30, 'name': 'maya'}], 'id': 2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.groupby`

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> dict1 = [{"id": 1, "name": "tamara", "age":23}, {"id": 1, "name": "mia", "age":14}, {"id": 1, "name": "teo", "age":33}, {"id": 2, "name": "maya", "age":30}]
>>> [{'id': k, 'new_key':[{k2:v2} for d in list(v) for k2,v2 in d.items() if k2!='id']} for k,v in groupby(dict1, itemgetter('id'))]
# [{'new_key': [{'age': 23}, {'name': 'tamara'}, {'age': 14}, {'name': 'mia'}, {'age': 33}, {'name': 'teo'}], 'id': 1}, {'new_key': [{'age': 30}, {'name': 'maya'}], 'id': 2}]
```